# Problems on Latex compiler Errors

Tags: miktex

File `mfirstuc.sty` not found. `\RequirePackage`, Any one can help me how to fix this error. I am importing all packages but I don't know what's going on?

Comment: Are you on MiKTeX?

Comment: [tag:egreg] yes, I am working on MiKTex

Comment: possible duplicate of http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/268216/usepackageglossaries-wont-work-after-miktex-update-reinstallation?lq=1 (see comments there)?

Answer (score 1):

Even i had the same problem. Import **\usepackage{mfirstuc}** in your preamble. This solved my problem. Hopes it solves your problem too.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Since `\usepackage` and `\RequirePackage` are essentially synonyms, I don't think it's relevant what name you're using.

Comment: Same problem with me but this doesn't solve it... :-(

Comment: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/268216/usepackageglossaries-wont-work-after-miktex-update-reinstallation?lq=1 Solved my problem! :-)