# \usepackage{glossaries} won't work after Miktex-Update/-Reinstallation

Tags: miktex, glossaries

I'm struggeling with the same error described in this post [Problems on Latex Compiler Errors](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/267861/problems-on-latex-compiler-errors). Here's an MWE

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{glossaries}
\begin{document}
Lipsum
\end{document}
```

which produces the error

```
! LaTeX Error: File `mfirstuc.sty' not found.
```

(see complete [log-file](https://copy.com/euyTmZap6HL4cONT))

Last week I updated packages (as user and admin), but got an "update l3kernel..." error message afterwards when trying to compile an MWE (Miktex, TeXStudio, pdflatex). After deinstallation of Miktex and reinstallation everything worked fine until I tried to use glossaries.

**Update**:

After the synchronization (thanks Ulrike!) the installation worked for mfirstuc.sty, but now `glossary-hypernav.sty` can't be found

```
! LaTeX Error: File `glossary-hypernav.sty' not found.
```

(see updated [log-file](https://copy.com/euyTmZap6HL4cONT) for details)

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Nicola Talbot (the author of `glossaries`) changed the package last week, splitting off the `mfirstuc` package from the `glossaries` bundle. Try to install that packages separately

Comment: Synchronize your local package databases in the package managers (user + admin) with menu repositories ->synchronize.

Comment: I am also encountering the same problem (LaTeX Error: File `glossary-hypernav.sty' not found.): have you found any solution? thank you

Answer (score 18):

I had the same problem. I followed  Ulrike's advice i.e. Synchronization of the local package databases (thanks Ulrike!!). It sorted out the initial issue.

Next I too ended up with the "glossary-hypernav.sty" not found error. I then went to Start-> All Programs -> MikTex 2.xx -> Maintenance(Admin) -> MikTex Package Manager (Admin) and scrolled down to glossary. I single-clicked on that, then on the plus (+) sign at the top of the window to add that package and it's all working now.

Thank you very much Ulrike for setting me on the right path - I had tried the second step several times with no result; the synchronisation was needed first.

(Forgot to add that before doing any of the above, as part of my efforts at trying to solve the problem I downloaded a copy of the "mfirstuc.sty" file and added it to my "C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\glossaries\base". However, I don't think this makes any difference.)

Comment: Thanks, that works :) After manually installing `glossary` and `glossaries` using MikTex Package Manager (Admin) everything is compiled without an error.

Comment: It is critical to do the synchronize in the Package manager after downloading the package.

Comment: can you take @user2600959 comment into your answer. This indeed is very critical.