# Mfirstuc.sty not found error at \usepackage{titletoc}

Tags: titletoc

```
\usepackage[nottoc,notlot,notlof,numbib]{tocbibind}
\usepackage[titletoc]{appendix}
\usepackage{titletoc}
```

One of these line is giving the error mfirstuc.sty not found. I tried installing package using miktex 2.9, it apparently does not know any such package.... I've no clue how to proceed...

Comment: may be related http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/268216/usepackageglossaries-wont-work-after-miktex-update-reinstallation